# How can I use a subquery as alias in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

This is my code. Its giving me an error.

```
select 
b.bill_no as 'Bill Number',
(select descript from SALE_TERMS where STERMS_CODE='99')=b.[99]
from BILLDET as b
```

Comment: what is it supposed to so? The part 
"9')=b.[99]"
makes no sense for me. What is the error?

Comment: The Error is, in billdet table there is column name [99] and in sale_terms table there is a row for [99] and i want to bring the descript value for [99], which is supposed to be the column name.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
SELECT
   b.bill_no as 'Bill Number',
   (SELECT descript FROM SALE_TERMS WHERE STERMS_CODE = '99') AS 'Code99'
FROM
   BILLDET as b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   b.bill_no as 'Bill Number',
   ST.[99]
FROM
   BILLDET as b
   CROSS JOIN
   (SELECT descript AS [99] FROM SALE_TERMS WHERE STERMS_CODE = '99') ST
```

or do you meanthis?

```
SELECT
   b.bill_no as 'Bill Number',
   ST.descript
FROM
   BILLDET as b
   JOIN
   SALE_TERMS st ON b.[99] = ST.STERMS_CODE
WHERE
   ST.STERMS_CODE = '99'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is almost right, except for the assignment, it should be an 'AS' statement containing the column name.
Also, it's a good thing to use TOP 1 in your subquery, in case the STERMS_CODE value is not unique:

```
SELECT
b.bill_no AS 'Bill Number',
(SELECT TOP 1 descript from SALE_TERMS WHERE STERMS_CODE='99') AS [99]
FROM BILLDET AS b
```

Comment: What I want to do is use the subquery as column name not row value. Your answer is doing the same.

Comment: I see. You want to create a dynamically named column based on a subquery. That's not going to work this way. Can you provide some sample input and output data?

Comment: there is no way this ever works. A SQL Statement assumes a "proper", i.e. stable, environment after compilation. You could do it with dynamic SQL,. but it takes 2 queries - one o get the field name, then some string magic, thne one to get the data.